# unable to mkdir in php on google cloud platform

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cloud, mkdir, platform

Hi I have a website on the google cloud platform using the PHP LAMP stack from bitnami I have an issue where `mkdir()` and `move_uploaded_file()` are not working. I am trying to create random folders to store user profile images. Currently i had to substitute the image storage onto the database which slows the update process of images or something. Here is the code i am having issues with

```
if(@$_FILES['profilepic']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || @$_FILES['profilepic']['type'] == 'image/png' || @$_FILES['profilepic']['type'] == 'image/gif' && @$_FILES['profilepic']['size'] < 1048576) {
 $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
 $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
 mkdir("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");


 if (file_exists("userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".@$_FILES['profilepic']['name']))
 {
   echo @$_FILES['profilepic']['name']."Already exists";
   echo "";
 }
 else
 {
   move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['profilepic']['tmp_name'], "userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES['profilepic']['name']);
   // echo "Uploaded and stored in: userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/" .@$_FILES['profilepic']['name'];
   $profile_pic_name = @$_FILES['profilepic']['name'];
   $pic_query = "UPDATE users SET profile_pic='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE username='$user'";
   $result = $connection->query($pic_query);
   if(!$result) die("Database access failed: " . $connection->error);
   header("Location: manage.php");
 }
}
  else {
 echo "Invalid File! Your Image must be no larger than 1MB and either a    .jpg, .png, .gif";
}
```

Does anyone have an idea on how i can add folders and images to the google cloud storage??

Comment: i was able to get help from the gcp team